# How to remove the extra array from wpdb->get_results

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I have an array:

```
$location= $wpdb->get_results("
                        SELECT
                            town, county, country
                        FROM
                            " . $wpdb->prefix . "table WHERE ID = " . $ID);
```

This will only ever return one row as ID is unique.

I need to get this data into an array so it looks like:

```
array("Base" => $basetype,
                  "Fields" => array("town"=>"Birmingham", "county"=>"West Midlands", "country"=>"UK"))
```

If I hard code this line the API works but if I try to use:

```
array("Base" => $basetype,
                  "Fields" => $location
```

I seem to add an extra array that I don't want:

```
Array ( [Base] => test [Fields] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [Town] => Birmingham [County] => West Midlands [Country] => UK
```

How can I avoid this extra array (`=> Array ( [0]`)? Is this something peculiar to WordPress? I have tried changing the format of `get_results`, to no avail.

Comment: you are doing something else wrong, is not that line that is adding that array, if that is not the code you are using, please post the EXACT code that you are using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might know that the SQL will only return one row, but your code doesn't! `get_results` returns all matching rows i.e. an array of rows (as either arrays or objects) - even if the result is just one row, it still returns it in an array.

**1 - Return just a single row using `get_row`**

You can use `get_row` to return just one result e.g.:

```
$location = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT town, county, country FROM " 
                           . $wpdb->prefix . "table WHERE ID = " . $ID,
                           ARRAY_A);
```

Note, you should use `ARRAY_A` in `get_row` to ensure the row is returned as an associative array.

**2 - Return all rows (and just use the first result)**

*Depending on where this code is used, you might want the code to keep returning an array so it is compatible with other places you use it. You can do this as follows:*

First, use `ARRAY_A`in `get_results` to ensure the rows are returned as an associative array:

```
$locations = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT town, county, country FROM " 
                              . $wpdb->prefix . "table WHERE ID = " . $ID,
                              ARRAY_A);
```

**2a - Use just the first row in your code:** As you know you only will have one row, you just need to get the first result from the array that was returned from the query:

```
$first_location = $locations[0];
```

Now `$first_location` contains the first (and only) row, so you can use it in the rest of your code (or you can use `$locations[0]` directly).

**2b - loop through all rows (even if it is just one):** If you also need this code to be reusable, you can loop through the results and process each individually. When your results only have one row, then the loop will only run once, e.g.:

```
foreach ($locations as $location){
    // Do your stuff here, using $location as before...
    // If you only have one result, then the loop will only run once
}
```

**References**

- [`get_row` Wordpress Developer Code Reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/get_row/)
- [`get_results` Wordpress Developer Code Reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/get_results/)

Comment: `get_row` worked without the need to use `ARRAY_A`. I thought I'd keep all my queries consistant. Not realised the result could be so different. Thank you.

Comment: @IanTurner Glad if worked! FYI if you are not using `ARRAY_A`, then your query is returning an `OBJECT` (this is the default for `get_row` and `get_results`). The code using this result must be set up to work with an object, rather than an array as you mention... just something to remember for future, if you need to make changes to that code or if you need to post other questions :)